# First uiwebview is showing url of second webview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

**Explanation:**  I have two viewcontrollers in my project. (Both of their class names are - ViewController) Each view controller have one uiwebview. 
When I test the app, the first uiwebview opens the url webpage of the second uiwebview. (The second uiwebview url is http://google.com and the first one is http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php, so the first uiwebview opens http://google.com)

Here's the code from the .m file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);


    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

     webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];

    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    webview2.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview2];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview2];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
```

How do I fix it so each uiwebviews opens their designated url.

First webview - http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php

Second webview - http://google.com


**ADDITIONAL:** Some are saying i have two outlets in one ViewController, where is that and how do I fix it so one webview is on each (2) viewcontroller.

Comment: FYI - Do not delete and repost your questions. That's bad form. If you have more info, you should update the previous question.

Comment: Your explanation is wrong. You have posted one view controller that contains two web views.

Comment: @rmaddy, how, I don't understand. It's TWO view controller with one webview on EACH.  Please show me where it says two on one viewcontroller.

Comment: @rmaddy http://i.stack.imgur.com/pXJWc.png

Comment: It's right there in the code you posted. You have two web view defined as properties in this one view controller class. The `viewDidLoad` method creates and add BOTH web views and add them both to this ONE view controller.

Comment: @rmaddy here? `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;`

Comment: two upvotes already . Nice question!

Comment: That's part of it. The important part is the code you wrote (or copy and pasted without understanding) in the `viewDidLoad` method. That's where you actually create and setup BOTH web views - one directly on top of and covering the other. This is my last comment. You deleted all of the other attempts to explain this to you in the question you just deleted. Please find some tutorials and read some documentation. Good luck.

Comment: @rmaddy can you edit the code to make it each one on different viewcontrollers.

Comment: Where are the two outlets on the same storyboard and where am I programming it again on the viewDidLoad? Please show me the code(s).

Comment: @T_77 I'm new to Objective-C, please help me.

Answer (score 1):

What rmaddy is saying is that what you wrote as your explanation and what the code shows are not the same. I understand you say you have two view controllers, but you only show the code for one. You are essentially creating one view that sits directly on top of another and has the same dimensions. You will never see the web view underneath this way. If you do something like this you should see both webviews, one on top of the other. That will show you that there really is two there, but one was just hidden behind the other:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView2;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);


    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];

    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

     webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    UIWebView *webview2=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height/2, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height/2)];
    NSString *url2=@"http://google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl2=[NSURL URLWithString:url2];

    NSURLRequest *nsrequest2=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl2];

    [webview2 loadRequest:nsrequest2];

    webview2.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview2];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview2];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
```

## Edit 1:

If you really want two different view controllers, you need to do something like this:

### File 1:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);


    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url=@"http://test.bithumor.co/test26.php";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

     webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
```

### File 2:

```
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController2

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);


    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSString *url=@"http://www.google.com";
    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

     webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
```

If you are using storyboards or nibs, then you would want to set each view controller to a different class. One will get set to ViewController, the other to ViewController2

## Edit 2:

To do this in one file you could do something like this:

### ViewController.h:

```
...
@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlString;
@end
```

### ViewController.m:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize scrollView;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    draw1 = 0;
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 300, 480, 55);
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(480, 55)];

    openMenu.frame = CGRectMake(220, 270, 60, 30);


    UIWebView *webview=[[UIWebView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];

    NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:self.urlString];
    NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];

    [webview loadRequest:nsrequest];

     webview.scrollView.bounces = NO;

    [self.view addSubview:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:webview];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: openMenu];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront: scrollView];
```

### File where you present your web view controller:

```
...
ViewController *webViewController = [[ViewController alloc] init];
webViewController.urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
[self presentViewController:webViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

### Or if it's presented via segue you can do set the urlString property in the prepareForSegue method

```
...
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
   if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourSegueIDHere"]) {
      ViewController *webViewController = (ViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
      webViewController.urlString = @"http://www.google.com";
   }
}
...
```

Comment: Is that the new edited code, that I should replace with?

Comment: Yes, I only modified two lines, but you can copy/paste the whole section. You should be able to see the two views this way.

Comment: It works, but that's not how I wanted it to be. I wanted it, one webview on EACH SEPARATE viewcontroller

Comment: Yeah then that code will look very different from the above. This was just to demonstrate that there really are two there. The first one was not loading the wrong URL, it was just being hidden. Do you want to have one view controller that dynamically loads different URLs or do you really want to create two different view controllers?

Comment: I want to different viewcontrollers to load a different uiwebview on each one

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 I've edited my answer to reflect your needs. Lmk if that works for you.

Comment: is there anyway to keep it on one viewcontroller?

Comment: Yes there is, but you would need to pass in what URL you would like to load into the view controller since it will be used multiple times. It sounds like we may be getting into the territory of a separate question though, so you may want to ask that question separately.

Comment: Can you alter my code to make it on one file. (I didn't down vote it)

Comment: @PHPWebDev101 added an example to show you where to add code to use one view controller instead of two. Hope that helps.

Comment: No, i need a code to keep the codes on one file but one uiwebview on each (2) viewcontrollers

Comment: Sorry not sure what you mean anymore?

Comment: I would like to keep all the code in one .m file but have two uiwebviews coded into it (ONE .m file) for two different view controllers. So one .m file with all the code and two different viewcontrollers with one webview on each.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do that but, to be honest, that's totally against how the structure of your app files is supposed to be. You can google around to see if it's possible, but 99.9999% of the time you will have one class interface/implementation per .m file. The solutions above will get you what you need and follow the proper file structures. Sorry I couldn't be more help!

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, there two possible scenarios:
First: simply what your calling 2 ViewControllers is actually 1 ViewController with two views, if this is the case add functionality to bring the one you one to front.
Second: you actually have two controllers. if your you are using the code you attached for both ViewControllers, then you will always end up with having the second web view in front of the first one. Both are loaded, but you can see the upper one.

I hope this helped in identifying the issue.